# Flashcards of Japanese animation, copyright

Tags: copyright

I am thinking of creating a website allowing users to learn Japanese language with flashcards. This website will be for education purpose only and totally free. Basically each flaschards contains a question and an answer about a short sequence of video to test the student understanding. These videos are short extracts from Japanese animation DVD (e.g. Dragon ball etc...).

Is the fact of displaying these flashcards on a non-profit education website copyright infringement?

Note : I dont know if it matters here, but the website will also display the link for the users to purchase the original DVD on Amazon etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, its copyright infringement**

You may be able to raise a fair dealing defence but it is by no means certain that it would be successful.